# Airflow variables and connections

Tags: variables, connection, airflow

I have a Airflow 1.10.11 running in an EC2 setup by my predecessors with docker-compose.
I wish to learn how to set it up. I have the docker-compose file. But i need all the configurations.
I know the config file can be found in scheduler container under /opt/bitnami/airflow/airflow.cfg.
There are many connections and variables and xcom in the UI. Where can I find them in which container?
Or how could I export them? some variables are encrypted and i can only see ***, so i could not recreate one by one in UI. Thanks

i saw the documantation on exporting connections using command: airflow connections export connections.json
where do i execute this command in CLI, in which container?

Comment: Just an update, i have successfully exported all variables via Airflow GUI in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can run on each airflow-* running container.

`docker exec -it airflow-worker bin/bash`

2. Or you can run with docker-compose from your machine . for more details see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#running-the-cli-commands)

`docker-compose run airflow-worker airflow [command]`

Comment: Thanks ozs, after exec into worker container, i am able to do list connections with: airflow connections -l. but there seem to be no export command. i dont know if it is because its version 1.10.11.

Comment: @KelvinChow try airflow connections --help to see commands options. if you can upgrade to version 2+ its better :-)

Comment: I have tried with --help, there is no export or anything close. currently is version 1. i think i just copy each connections and recreate in new airflow latest version.